# adding script to build.gradle

Tags: python, groovy, build, gradle

I have a `build.gradle` file. I need to add a code that executes a python script which I have written.
Can anyone tell me how to do it?
The `build.gradle` is written in groovy . 
So, please ask more questions if you feel my question is not sufficient.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Take a look at the [Exec](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) task. It can be used for running command line processes.

You could create a task like:

```
task runPython(type:Exec) {
   workingDir 'path_to_script'

   commandLine 'python', 'my_script.py'
}
```